# .htaccess redirect everything

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

here is my situation...

I have one domain

> www.ionzuniverse.com OR ionzuniverse.com

I was looking for a way to redirect everything from that domain to a subdomain such as:

> iu.ionzuniverse.com

To be specific I need everything that looks like this

> www.ionzuniverse.com/somepage OR ionzuniverse.com/somepage

To redirect to something like this

> iu.ionzuniverse.com/somepage

**How can I use htaccess to do something like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ionzuniverse.com$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ionzuniverse.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://iu.ionzuniverse.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Rob, that worked, but only if I entered in www. (how can the htaccess do both?)

Comment: Both meaning www.ionzunivers.com and simply ionzunivers.com? Updated to handle that.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you! I hate working with .htaccess, but when it works its godly!